# How much time comet is within the Earth's orbit?

Tags: orbit, earth, comets

Comet on the parabola orbit flies by Sun.

I would like to know what is comet's full energy? What is its distance from Sun at perihelion?

Comment: This question is too vague? Which comet? The title is not explained in the post.

Comment: any of. Its perihelion speed is 94 km/s.

Comment: thts all I ve got

Comment: Are these homework problems? If so, you should disclose that. It seems that such a question would be accompanied by a diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the comet is on a parabolic trajectory, then its total energy (kinetic plus gravitational potential) is zero. This enables you to solve for the perihelion distance if you know the perihelion velocity (or vice-versa). The comet always travels at the escape speed appropriate for its distance from the Sun.

This and other useful properties of parabolic trajectories are discussed on the appropriate [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_trajectory).